# Building an accumumulator object within an async loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two models, one with changes, I am looping through and doing change detection against the same model for a given ID.

I setup [a stackblitz repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tj-ng6-dynprops) to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish (non-functional at the moment, just a the code I am trying to implement is.)

Is this a scoping issue?  Is this an object mutation issue?

I need to get a (filtered) list of changes transformed into a single object with properties and values for all the new updates to be posted to [this api/backend](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api#create-with-json-array).

Crux of code from SB..

```
findDeltas = async (newModels: any[]) => {
  const ids = newModels.map(m => m.id);
  let updates: any[] = [];

  await newModels.map = async (newModel) => {
    const id = +newModel.id;
    const model = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1')
      .then(resp => resp.json())[id]; // pretend collection index = item id

    let updateObj = {};
    for (const key of newModel) {
      console.log('Found Key: ' + key);

      // Just filter for changes in one property for this demo
      if (newModel[key] !== model[key] && key === 'title') {
        updateObj[key] = model[key];
        console.log('Update found!: ' + updateObj[key]);
      }
    }

    console.log('Updates found: ' + this.updates.length);
    this.updates.push(updateObj);
    console.log('Updates total: ' + this.updates.length);
  });

  console.log('Updates final: ' + this.updates.length);
}
```

Currently, outside of the loop, the `updateObj` object is still undefined by the time it returns.

PS: I also tried...

```
Object.defineProperty(updt, key, {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: proposedChange[key]
})
```

as well as...

```
//changedFieldList.forEach(key => {
for (const key of changedFieldList) {
```

and...

```
//const updateObjectPerId = await Promise.all(proposedChanges.map(async (proposedChange) => {
const updateObjectPerId = await proposedChanges.map(async (proposedChange) => {
```

Comment: What `await newModels.map = async (newModel)` is supposed to do? Whatever it is, it's wrong. `.then(resp => resp.json())[id]` - this certainly won't work as you expect, you're getting id property of a promise, which is likely undefined. It's unclear which parts of code are genuinely wrong and which parts are wrong because it's 'non-functional at the moment'.

Comment: I wish I could answer your question, but sorting that out is the kind of input I am looking for.

Comment: I'm just looking for a successful pattern to build an object from an array of key/value pairs.  What you see in the stackblitz is the various things I've tried toward that end.

Answer (score 0):

A [kind soul](https://angular.io/api/core/KeyValueDiffer) [pointed me](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=5b1256fe016ae21a4c034cd1) towards Angular's [KeyValueDiffer](https://angular.io/api/core/KeyValueDiffer#keyvaluediffer) and [SimpleChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges#simplechanges) which appear to be the answers to this question that I wasn't sure how to ask.